# define variable inside getscript and use it outside of it? (fetching an avatar from a json file and use it in loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tumblr

been losing my mind over this for a day now. I have this array that has a nested array in it like this:
`[[username, desc],[username 2, desc 2], [...]]`

my goal is to integrate the values in a `<li>` for each user and append it inside a list with the "voilalescops" #id. however, i'd like to add the avatar as well, and for this i go and fetch it from a JSON file that uses the username value. my code is nearly done but i can't figure out why the avatar remains undefined :/ here's what i have so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= lespotescorrect.length; i++) { 
                            var cop_pseud = lespotescorrect[i][0];
                            var cop_desc = lespotescorrect[i][1];
                            
                            var lienapi = "https://" + cop_pseud + ".tumblr.com/api/read/json?num=1";
                            var lavatar = '<li><a href="https://' + cop_pseud + '.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">';
                            
                            var avatar = '';
                            $.getScript(lienapi, function() { 
                                readData = tumblr_api_read;
                                avatar = readData.posts[0]['tumblelog']['avatar_url_64'];
                                lavatar += '<img src="' + avatar + '"/>'; 
                            });
                            console.log(avatar)
                            
                            lavatar += '</a><div class="infobulle"><strong>' + cop_pseud + '</strong><span>' + cop_desc + '</span></div></li>';
                            
                            console.log(lavatar);
                            
                            $('#voilalescops').append(lavatar);
                            
                        }
```

**if you need more context**, this will go on a tumblr blog and is supposed to display a friend list (different from the list of blogs followed) by showing a list of avatars with tooltips displaying username and a personal description for each. the proprietor of the blog will be able to simply enter a list of usernames + desc in their theme editor and the code will display the rest automatically. for now everything displays fine except the avatars... you can check out the result here https://dags-backup.tumblr.com/ (test blog) in [the right sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8niV.jpg). (i'm sorry it's all in french btw).

Thanks in advance if u help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I realized doing what I wanted with `getScript` seemed to be impossible, as it wasn't possible to use my `cop_pseud` and `cop_desc` variable inside the `getscript` loop. However, for what I wanted to do, I found out it was possible to use another method to fetch the avatar, a method that also permits to fetch avatars for blogs that are only visible from dashboard: the API permits the use of `https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/BlogID.tumblr.com/avatar/64` to get the avatar, so i simply put that value inside a variable and rolled with it. Everything works fine now!

Here my code, which is actually much simpler, if anyone needs to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lespotescorrect.length; i++) { 
  var cop_pseud = lespotescorrect[i];
  if (cop_pseud != undefined) {
    var lienavatar = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+ cop_pseud +".tumblr.com/avatar/64";
    var lavatar = '<li><a href="https://' + cop_pseud + '.tumblr.com/" target="_blank" title="'+ cop_pseud +'"><img src="' + lienavatar + '" alt="Avatar '+ cop_pseud +'"/></a><div class="infobulle"><strong>' + cop_pseud + '</strong><span>' + cop_desc + '</span></div></li>'; 
                                
    $('#voilalescops').append(lavatar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get a version working on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/4xjkLc7t/

Here is the new code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var laliste = $('.listedescopains').text().replace(/ /g,'');
        var lespotes = laliste.split(/[,;]+/).filter((v) => v != '');
        var lespotescorrect = [];
        while (lespotes.length > 0) {
            var chunk = lespotes.splice(0,2);
            lespotescorrect.push(chunk)
        }
        lespotescorrect.filter((v) => v != '');
        for (var i = 0; i <= lespotescorrect.length; i++) {
            var cop_pseud = lespotescorrect[i][0];
            var cop_desc = lespotescorrect[i][1];
            var lienapi = "https://" + cop_pseud + ".tumblr.com/api/read/json?num=1";
            $.getScript(lienapi, function() {
                readData = tumblr_api_read;
                var avatar = readData.posts[0].tumblelog.avatar_url_64; // changed this to use dot notation
                var name = readData.posts[0].tumblelog.name; // this is new reading the name from the data;
                var template = "<img src='" + avatar +"'/>";
                var lavatar = '<li><a href="https://' + name + '.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">' +template+ '</a><div class="infobulle"><strong>' + name + '</strong><span>' + cop_desc + '</span></div></li>';
                $('#voilalescops').append(lavatar); // append the item inside the getScript function
            });
        }
    });
```

Basically as we are making the `getScript` call for as many times as there are items in the `lespotescorrect` array, we can simply append the `<li>` item inside the getScript call, so each time it iterates through the different users, it should retrieve the correct avatar for that user. Hope this makes sense.

**UPDATE**

I have created a new variable which reads the blog name from the tumblr api response. So this line is new:

`var name = readData.posts[0].tumblelog.name;`

And for `cop_pseud` we need to update that to the `name` variable in the template string. I don't really understand the description part, if that is in the data being returned from the tumblr api you can just create a variable similar to the others.

I have updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/4xjkLc7t/) and am now console logging each json object as it is returned. That has description and title. See attached.
[image]

Comment: thanks so much for helping! i thought about that but the problem is the cop_pseud and cop_desc variables get updated as well and so the name and description displayed for all <li> items are the same, aka the ones in the last loops :( any idea how i could display them before getscript changes them?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am not sure about the description as you are pulling that from an element on the page, but the rest I have updated.

Comment: it is indeed closer to what i want to do, however my problem is that, if possible, i would like to give the user the possibility to add their own description for each friend, which is what the "cop_desc" variable should contain, i'm just having trouble using that variable inside the getscript call :/

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying is possible. You need somewhere to persist this data in a tumblr database. Or you need some form on the site to display this information, or maybe this is just for you to enter free text? Either way I think this is quite tricky, unless perhaps you hard code it in someway.